# Flutter - Unhandled Exception: setState() called after dispose() AND _StreamBuilderBaseState

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am getting the following error when changing device orientation:

```
E/flutter (31741): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(166)] Unhandled Exception: setState() called after dispose(): _StreamBuilderBaseState<List<ScheduledActivity>, AsyncSnapshot<List<ScheduledActivity>>>#afadb(lifecycle state: defunct, not mounted)
E/flutter (31741): This error happens if you call setState() on a State object for a widget that no longer appears in the widget tree (e.g., whose parent widget no longer includes the widget in its build). This error can occur when code calls setState() from a timer or an animation callback.
E/flutter (31741): The preferred solution is to cancel the timer or stop listening to the animation in the dispose() callback. Another solution is to check the "mounted" property of this object before calling setState() to ensure the object is still in the tree.
E/flutter (31741): This error might indicate a memory leak if setState() is being called because another object is retaining a reference to this State object after it has been removed from the tree. To avoid memory leaks, consider breaking the reference to this object during dispose().
E/flutter (31741): #0      State.setState.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1204:9)
E/flutter (31741): #1      State.setState (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1239:6)
E/flutter (31741): #2      _StreamBuilderBaseState._subscribe.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/async.dart:140:9)
E/flutter (31741): #3      _StartWithValueStream.listen.<anonymous closure> (package:moor/src/utils/start_with_value_transformer.dart:49:17)
E/flutter (31741): #4      _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1182:47)
E/flutter (31741): #5      _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1093:19)
E/flutter (31741): #6      _CustomZone.runGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:997:7)
E/flutter (31741): #7      _CustomZone.bindCallbackGuarded.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/zone.dart:1037:23)
E/flutter (31741): #8      _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1190:13)
E/flutter (31741): #9      _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1093:19)
E/flutter (31741): #10     _CustomZone.runGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:997:7)
E/flutter (31741): #11     _CustomZone.bindCallbackGuarded.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/zone.dart:1037:23)
E/flutter (31741): #12     _microtaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:41:21)
E/flutter (31741): #13     _startMicrotaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:50:5)
E/flutter (31741):
```

Now, I am aware [about the `if (mounted) setState` fix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49340116/setstate-called-after-dispose) - the thing, however, is I don't use `setState` in my app, since I am using `bloclibrary`.
Additionally, looking at the error, I can see `StreamBuilder<List<ScheduledActivity>>`, which is the only clue to the following code snippets, which causes the issue:

```
...
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return StreamBuilder<List<ScheduledActivity>>(
      stream: RepositoryProvider.of<AppDatabase>(context)
          .scheduledActivitiesDao
          .watchActivitiesByPlant(widget.plantId),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {

        if (snapshot.hasError) print('>>>> DB error - ${snapshot.error}');
        if (!snapshot.hasData) return ProgressIndicatorWidget();

        return Text('items = ${snapshot.data.length}');
      },
    );
  }
...
```

Two notes on the above code:

1. The Widget, which `build` function I posted above is `StatefulWidget`, however, even if I refactor it to `StatelessWidget`, I have the same error
2. The issue arises only when I switch from **Landscape** to **Portrait** mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the issue is related to the fact, I was creating the `Stream` each time the `build` method is called.

How to refactor the code:

1. Add `Stream<List<ScheduledActivity>> _stream;`
2. Set its value here:

```
  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    super.didChangeDependencies();
    _stream = RepositoryProvider.of<AppDatabase>(context)
        .scheduledActivitiesDao
        .watchActivitiesByPlant(widget.plantId);
  }
```

3. Replace

`RepositoryProvider.of<AppDatabase>context).scheduledActivitiesDao.watchActivitiesByPlant( widget.plantId),`

with
`stream: _stream,`