# Flutter auth firebase getx setstate() called after dispose

Tags: firebase, flutter, flutter-getx

I'm trying to create a flutter app with getx. Particularly in the authentication section, I have the following error:

> E/flutter ( 8992): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: setState() called after dispose(): _LogButtonState#3e8d6(lifecycle state: defunct, not mounted)
> E/flutter ( 8992): This error happens if you call setState() on a State object for a widget that no longer appears in the widget tree (e.g., whose parent widget no longer includes the widget in its build). This error can occur when code calls setState() from a timer or an animation callback.
> E/flutter ( 8992): The preferred solution is to cancel the timer or stop listening to the animation in the dispose() callback. Another solution is to check the "mounted" property of this object before calling setState() to ensure the object is still in the tree.
> E/flutter ( 8992): This error might indicate a memory leak if setState() is being called because another object is retaining a reference to this State object after it has been removed from the tree. To avoid memory leaks, consider breaking the reference to this object during dispose().
> E/flutter ( 8992): #0      State.setState. (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1085:9)
> E/flutter ( 8992): #1      State.setState (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1120:6)
> E/flutter ( 8992): #2      _LogButtonState.build. (package:sneakychat/Screens/Authentication/login.dart:231:9)
> E/flutter ( 8992): 
> E/flutter ( 8992):

The code for the authentication controller is the following:

```
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_facebook_auth/flutter_facebook_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:google_sign_in/google_sign_in.dart';

import '../Globals/globals.dart';

class AuthController extends GetxController {
  final FirebaseAuth _auth = firebaseAuth;

  late Rx<User?> _firebaseUser;
  late Rx<GoogleSignInAccount?> _googleSignInAccount;

  //UserModel get user => _firebaseUser.value;

  late GoogleSignIn googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn();
  //var a = googleSignIn.currentUser;

  @override
  onReady() {
    super.onReady();
    print("##########Im Reasdy###########");
    googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn();

    // Load current user
    _firebaseUser = Rx<User?>(_auth.currentUser);
    _googleSignInAccount = Rx<GoogleSignInAccount?>(googleSignIn.currentUser);

    // Bind Streams for listeners
    _firebaseUser.bindStream(_auth.userChanges());
    _googleSignInAccount.bindStream(googleSignIn.onCurrentUserChanged);

    // Call workers to update auth state
    ever(_firebaseUser, _manageAuthState);
    ever(_googleSignInAccount, _manageAuthStateGoogle);
  }

  // Manage the auth state
  _manageAuthState(User? user) {
    print("Firebase auth state active :D");
    if (user == null) {
      Get.offAllNamed("/LogIn");
    } else {
      Get.offAllNamed("/Home");
    }
  }

  // Manage the auth state regarding google's user state
  _manageAuthStateGoogle(GoogleSignInAccount? googleSignInAccount) {
    print("Google auth state active");
    if (googleSignInAccount == null) {
      Get.offAllNamed("/LogIn");
    } else {
      Get.offAllNamed("/Home");
    }
  }

  // Sign with google account
  Future<void> signupGoogle() async {
    final GoogleSignIn googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn();
    try {
      final GoogleSignInAccount? googleSignInAccount =
      await googleSignIn.signIn();
      _googleSignInAccount.value = googleSignInAccount;

      if (googleSignInAccount != null) {
        final GoogleSignInAuthentication googleSignInAuthentication =
        await googleSignInAccount.authentication;
        final AuthCredential authCredential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(
            idToken: googleSignInAuthentication.idToken,
            accessToken: googleSignInAuthentication.accessToken);

        // Bind Google account with Firebase account
        UserCredential resultUser = await _auth.signInWithCredential(
            authCredential);

        print(resultUser.credential);
        // Set a listener for the user
        _firebaseUser.value = resultUser.user;
        print(resultUser.user);

        // Store user data if its new
        /*User user = User(
          name: username,
          email: email,
          uid: cred.user!.uid,
          profilePhoto: downloadUrl,
        );
        await firestore
            .collection('users')
            .doc(cred.user!.uid)
            .set(user.toJson());*/

        Get.offAllNamed("/Home");
      }
    } catch (exc) {
      print(exc);
      Get.snackbar(
          'Something went wrong',
          "We couldn't connect with google's server",
          snackPosition: SnackPosition.TOP,
        backgroundColor: Colors.amber,
        colorText: Colors.white
      );
    }
  }

  Future<void> logoutGoogle() async {
    print("Sign out!");
    await googleSignIn.signOut();
    await _auth.signOut();

    print(googleSignIn.currentUser?.email);
    print("#################################");
    print(_firebaseUser.value?.uid);
    print("#################################");
    //Get.offAllNamed("/LogIn");
  }

  signIn() {}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can stop listening to the animation in the dispose() callback or cancel the timer.

Another solution is to check the mounted property of the state class of your widget before calling setState().
For Example:

```
 if (mounted) {
  setState(() {
    // Your code here
  });
}
```

Comment: I'm afraid I'm not following you. What timer am I listening to?

Comment: Please refer following answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49340116/setstate-called-after-dispose?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

Dispose the worker on `onClose()`.

Comment: what worker should i dispose? The ever(_firebaseUser, _manageAuthState) or ever(_googleSignInAccount, _manageAuthStateGoogle).