# setState() called after dispose() error after calling async function

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, setstate

I have this button that uploads to Firestore a picture that the user selects and stores the picture url into a varialble to be used to update the user's information.

SELECTION BUTTON calls selectFile().

```
// SELECTING FILE FOR UPLOAD
  Future selectFile() async {
    final result = await FilePicker.platform
        .pickFiles(allowMultiple: false, type: FileType.image, withData: true);
    if (result == null) return;

    setState(() {
      pickedFile = result.files.first;
      texto = Text(pickedFile!.name);
    });
  }
```

This successfully changes the state of pickedFiles and Texto variable.

Then I have this other button later in the code that calls uploadFile() and then exits the page with navigator.pop(context).

```
// UPLOADING FILE AND RETRIEVING DOWNLOAD LINK
  Future uploadFile() async {
    var fileBytes = pickedFile?.bytes;
    var fileName = pickedFile?.name;
    var ref = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child('UserImages/$fileName');
    if (fileBytes == null) {
      return '';
    }
    TaskSnapshot uploadedFile = await ref.putData(fileBytes);
    url = await ref.getDownloadURL();
    log(url);
    if (uploadedFile.state == TaskState.success) {
      setState(() {    <<<<<<<<--------- setState() called after dispose() ERROR HERE 
        _petImage = url;
      });
    }
  }
```

The function does upload the picture to FireStore and even produces a link (tested by using log(url)) but when it reaches the set state it fails.
I have no idea why this is not updating the state of the _petImage variable which stored outside of the main build(context) together with the other variables suck as pickedFile and texto. the setState work fine in other functions but in this function is not working .
what could I be doing wrong here?

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49340116/setstate-called-after-dispose answer your question?

Comment: setState shouldn't be called when uploading an image or sending data to external storage. thats the reason why you are getting error

Answer (score 0):

It is safe to check if the state is `mounted` on async and then perform setState.

```dart
_() async {
  if (mounted) {
    setState(() {});
  }
}
```